# Newbie Form Question: I'm only getting hidden fields

Tags: forms

I am trying to produce a form that only consists of 1 button. I have created a tab in the user menu screen with the following...

```
  $items['user/%/user_options'] = array(
    'title' => 'Newsletter/Membership Subscription',
    'description' => 'Allows user to subscribe or unsubscribe to the newletter and membership.',
    'page callback' => 'user_options_subscribe_choices',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'file' => 'user_options.user.inc',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
```

...then in user_option.user.inc I have this...

```
function user_options_subscribe_choices($wildcard) {
$build = array();

//check that the user id is valid...
if (is_numeric($wildcard) && ($account = user_load($wildcard))) {

    //return correct forms...
    if(in_array('Newsletter Subscriber', $account->roles)) {
        $build['form_one'] = drupal_get_form('delete_newsletter_subscription_form');
    } else {
        $build['form_one'] = drupal_get_form('add_newsletter_subscription_form');
    }

    if(in_array('Paying Member', $account->roles)) {
        $build['form_two'] = drupal_get_form('delete_membership_form');
    } else {
        $build['form_two'] = drupal_get_form('add_membership_form');
    }

    return $build;
    //return drupal_get_form('add_membership_form');
}else{
    return drupal_not_found();
}
}

function add_newsletter_subscription_form(&$form_state){
$form = array();

$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    //'#description' => 'You are not currently recieving SCiO newsletters.',
    '#value' => t('Subscribe to the SCiO Newsletter'),
    //'#attributes' => array('onclick' => "javascript:get(this.parentNode);"),
);

$form['choice'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t('Cake or pie?'),
'#description' => t('Would you like cake or pie?'),
'#options' => array(
    'cake' => t('Cake please'),
    'pie' => t('Pie I guess'),
),
'#default_value' => 'cake',
'#required' => TRUE,
);

return $form;
}
```

I have only given 1 example of the form function

...Now the odd thing is, is that I do see 2 forms in the html. BUT! they consist only of hidden fields.

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: What is add_membership_form code?

Comment: Maybe some broken form template interfering with default output. As an aside, you should probably use `%user` in your menu path, then the $account object will be already loaded, via `user_load` in the callback.

Comment: I am using $account to check that the supplied user id is valid. How would I handle an invalid user id in this way if I passed %user?
Also, there is no form template being used. 
I will repost the question in a less demanding format but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_newsletter_subscription_form(&$form_state){
    $form = array();

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        //'#description' => 'You are not currently recieving SCiO newsletters.',
        '#value' => t('Subscribe to the SCiO Newsletter'),
        //'#attributes' => array('onclick' => "javascript:get(this.parentNode);"),
    );

    $form['choice'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Cake or pie?'),
    '#description' => t('Would you like cake or pie?'),
    '#options' => array(
        'cake' => t('Cake please'),
        'pie' => t('Pie I guess'),
    ),
    '#default_value' => 'cake',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    return $form;
    }
```

[image]

You missed the first argument of this function $form.

```
function delete_newsletter_subscription_form($form, &$form_state){
$form = array();

$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    //'#description' => 'You are not currently recieving SCiO newsletters.',
    '#value' => t('Subscribe to the SCiO Newsletter'),
    //'#attributes' => array('onclick' => "javascript:get(this.parentNode);"),
);

$form['choice'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t('Cake or pie?'),
'#description' => t('Would you like cake or pie?'),
'#options' => array(
    'cake' => t('Cake please'),
    'pie' => t('Pie I guess'),
),
'#default_value' => 'cake',
'#required' => TRUE,
);

return $form;
}
```

[image]